# Applications of De-Bruijn Sequences in "Pure Mathematics"

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, gm.general-mathematics, enumerative-combinatorics, applications

I know of a few applications of De-Bruijn Sequences and De Bruijn Graphs in combinatorics, applied mathematics, Engineering and computer science. But I have only found one application of De Bruijn sequences in "pure mathematics", specifically in Diophantine approximations,  which is the following: http://eprints.whiterose.ac.uk/126995/1/160507953v3.pdf

Do you know of any other such applications of De Bruijn sequences in "Pure Mathematics"?

Comment: I reject the premise.  Combinatorics is already an area of pure mathematics!

Comment: Why pure mathematics is in quotation marks?

Comment: Of course Combinatorics is an area of pure mathematics. My question is, is there any non-combinatorial applications. Since sometimes things from combinatorics tend to pop up in other fields of mathematics.

Answer (score 4):

De Bruijn graphs (or, rather, their subgraphs) play a significant role in symbolic dynamics where they are known under the name of **Rauzy graphs**.

Comment: De Bruijn graphs are also commonly used in [de novo genome assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_novo_sequence_assemblers).

Comment: @Max Alekseyev Sure - actually the termnology in this area is different - their de Bruijn graphs are subgraphs of the classical ones (i.e., what is called Rauzy graphs in symbolic dynamics). But the question was about "pure mathematics".